# Need to integrate map widget with a basic search results listings page using IDX Broker

Tags: wordpress, idx, idxbroker

I am using Move-in Ready child theme (V 1.0.5) Equity (v 1.6.2) and ,the website link is [www.tampatogulfhomes.com](http://www.tampatogulfhomes.com).

On clicking a 'basic search' widget search button in header right section, I am facing difficulty in integrating a map with the basic search results. Instead, a basic search widget is getting displayed

[image: Home page]
[image: Results page]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by setting my preferences in IDX broker dashboard.The path for the tab is Preferences->Global Preferences->Results and alsoMap tab